# Should lower and upper bounds for a distribution count as parameters in AIC model selection

Tags: maximum-likelihood, model-selection

Suppose we want a random variable $X$ to be constrained and thereby to lie within specified bounds other than the natural bounds of the underlying distribution.

This should be understood such that if PDF of the underlying distribution is $f(x)$, the CDF is $F(x)$, $l$ is a lower constraint for the distribution, and $u$ is the upper bound, then the truncated and shifted distribution is determined by

$ f_{trunc}(x)=\frac{f(x)}{F(u)-F(l)}$, if $l\leq x \leq u$ and $f_{trunc}(x)=0$ otherwise.

Should $u$ and $l$ be counted as parameters in AIC model selection?

Suppose the underlying distribution in question is compared to (a version of) the Pareto distribution where a lower threshold (as a scale) is already part of the parameters and it is therefore penalized accordingly.

Comment: If the lower & upper bounds are known, no; if they're estimated, unfortunately the regularity conditions under which AIC is derived are violated.